# SQLDataReader does not show value of column with double colon in field name

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

A `Select` query works fine when I enter it in SQL Server Management Studio on SQL Server:

```
SELECT [00:00] 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE whatevercondition ...
```

The column name is "00:00" - it has a double colon. When I try to get the value from this column in a VB.net function with the help of a `SqlDataReader`, the result is always an error:

> Column does not exist

I have tried to put the column name in all variations of brackets, quotation marks, without brackets at all etc. I still can not retrieve the value in the table.

My VB.NET code:

```
Dim Counter_Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim Counter_Table As New DataTable
Dim Counter_Reader As SqlDataReader
Dim SQLTemp As String
Dim TheField as String
Dim result as String

TheField = "[00:00]"

SQLTemp = "SELECT " & TheField & " FROM MY_TABLE WHERE whatevercondition ..."

Data_CMD_Counter = New SqlCommand(SQLTemp, MyDatabaseConnection)
Counter_Adapter.SelectCommand = Core.Data_CMD_Counter
Counter_Adapter.Fill(Counter_Table)
Counter_Reader = Core.Data_CMD_Counter.ExecuteReader

If Counter_Reader.HasRows = True Then
    result = Counter_Table.Rows(0)(TheField).ToString() 'This line causes the error: Column "[00:00]" not included in the table.

Else
End If
```

How do have to quote/escape the column name correctly so that it works in a `SqlDataReader`?

Comment: Careful `"SELECT " & TheField & " FROM MY_TABLE WHERE..."` is a big injection issue. You need to ensure you're properly quoting your objects if they're Dynamic (no `"[" & YourColumn & "]"` isn't properly quoting). Personally I would pass `TheField` as a parameter and use `spexecutesql` and `QUOTENAME`. Also, ideally you want to avoid columns that have special characters and therefore need to be delimit identified. Stick to alphanumerical characters and (if you need) underscores (`_`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
TheField = "[00:00]"
SQLTemp = "SELECT " & TheField & " FROM MY_TABLE WHERE whatevercondition ..."
```

should be

```
TheField = "00:00"
SQLTemp = "SELECT [" & TheField.Replace("]", "]]") & "] FROM MY_TABLE WHERE whatevercondition ..."
```

The name is `00:00`.  Not `[00:00]`.  This is a [delimited identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017) and the `[` and `]` are only present in TSQL, and enable the parser to tell where the name begins and ends when the name doesn't follow the rules for regular identifiers.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the injection issue, especially if `TheField` is coming from user input, or can be manipulated.

Comment: I have also tried to pass this without brackets. In this case I get the error earlier (when filling the adapter): `Incorrect syntax near ':'` I had added the brackets because with brackets it gives a correct result in SQL Studio.

Comment: The brackets are in the SQL Statement, they just aren't part of the column name. @Larnu you can't parameterize column names.

Comment: No David, but you can properly quote them, and just wrapping a value with brackets doesn't properly quote something; especially when the value is coming from user input. Just like with a literal string that is injected, a column name (wrapped) in brackets that is injected can suffer from SQL Injection. For example `TheField = "name] FROM sys.objects;--"`

Comment: For that reason, that is why I prefer to pass the column name as a parameter to the SQL statement, then use `QUOTENAME` on said parameter within the SQL and use `sp_executesql` to execute the dynamic statement.

Comment: No worries. Injection is a personal bug bare of mine (as it's still far too common in the Industry) but that solves the issue too. +1 from me.

Comment: @Larnu: Frankly, I´m not so familiar with the SQL Injection issue here, but although `TheField` is a variable it´s not accessible to a user. It´s an internal query. The table is a timetable with the time as fieldnames. And I need to go through all these field names  So agree with your expertise, but assuming that this is a given structure which I can not change, how can I access these fields with the double colon in their names?

Comment: The answer above should work for you.  If not, add a short but complete repro to your question.

Comment: @David Browne - Yes, it´s working. After some attempts I have found the right way to build the query. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ordinal index of the column, rather than the column name.

Like this, using 0 for the first column in your `SELECT` statement:

```
result = Counter_Table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
```

Comment: In this case the error is "Column 0 does not exist". It seems that the DataAdapter is not filled at all.